# Can not access anonymous Printer Windows 7

Tags: samba

Why to set up cups or samba, because when print test page is failed (always show authentication user). Windows already set shared with anonymous.

[image: Preview Detail Image >>]

Answer (score 0):

You will still need to authenticate with the username "GUEST" and an empty password.

Also, you may need to install smbclient and specify the correct workgroup in /etc/samba/smb.conf. If the workgroup doesn't match, the authentication fails.